# RMS of a complex waveform

Tags: power-supply, basic, rms

For a complex waveform as follows:

[image]

One can find the squared rms of the complete waveform by finding rms of individual components and then square multiplying it with the corresponding duty cycle.
$$s_n = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T u(t)^2 dt$$
$$u_{rms} = \sqrt{d_1 s_1 +d_2 s_2 + \cdots + d_n s_n}$$

**EDIT1:**
For example finding the rms of following waveform,

[image]

$$ I_{rms} = \sqrt{d_1 I_1^2 + d_2 I_2^2}$$
Is the above method also applicable for sinusoidal wave or any other non-linear waveforms?

**EDIT2:**
If I want to calculate the rms of a sine function defined from 54 degrees to 180 degrees with peak value of 27.44 I get 11.48 but the actual answer is 12.66.

$$ RMS = \sqrt{27.44^2 * 0.35 * 0.5} = 11.48 $$
here, duty cycle = 0.35

Comment: I don't see how the \$u_i\$'s are defined. What is \$u_2\$ for example?

Comment: The diagram is just an idea of a complex waveform. $u_i$ could be any line.

Comment: but \$u_i\$ is **one** voltage value while the voltage at  section \$i\$ is not (necessarily) constant. So what dos \$u_i\$ mean? The starting voltage, the final voltage, the average voltage... of that section???

Comment: @Ansh Kumar: I know that that is "just an idea". Still the symbols used need to have a well defined meaning (I'm not asking for numerical values)

Comment: \$u_i\$ is the segment extended over the period \$T\$. I have edited and put an example in the question.

Comment: I guess I start to understand, if \$u_i\$'s can mean *any* \$u_i(t)\$. But then you have answered your question yourself. Yes.

Comment: But I'm not getting answer for sinusoidal waveform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the formula is correct. If you reverse engineer it a bit, it will make a bit more sense.

For instance, \$d_1s_1\$ is the power contribution from \$s_1\$ if the waveform that produced \$s_1\$ (\$u_1\$, via the integral) was present for the whole of the period from 0 to T.

Ditto all the other contributors.

For this waveform: -

[image]

If you put numbers down like \$d_1\$ = \$d_2\$ i.e. 50% duty cycle with T=1, \$I_2\$=5 and \$I_1\$=1, the RMS calculated by the equation in the question would produce this: -

\$\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\$ = \$\sqrt{13}\$

Then if you compared this with the more conventional approach of assuming it was a symetrical square wave with peak values of +2 and -2 (superimposed on a DC level of 3) you would get: -

\$\sqrt{2^2+3^2}\$ = \$\sqrt{13}\$

Comment: So, is it valid for sinusoidal and any other non-linear functions also ? Because on calculation I was getting wrong answer(small error).

Comment: It is valid as far as I'm concerned - maybe you made some rounding error?

Comment: Okay, I'm putting my calculation in the question above.

Comment: I don't understand the numbers in your calculation, like, where does the 0.35 come from? Ditto the 0.5? Also what is T given that the partial duration of the sinewave is 0.2 x 360 degrees?

Comment: rms of the sine is \$(\text{peak value})/\sqrt{2}\$ so in the final calculation of rms where we have to square its value, I replaced it with \$ (\text{peak value})^2/2\$ and 0.35 is the duty cycle 126/360 = 0.35

Comment: What happened to the 54 degrees that you mentioned i.e. 126-54 = 72 which, as a duty cycle is 0.2 for a full sinewave of 360 degrees. Also, for the other 288 degrees what happens to the waveform? You are not being very clear.

Comment: Yes you are right, the conduction time was 126 degrees from 54 to 180 degrees, so the duty cycle is (180-54)/360 = 126/360 =0.35

Comment: Well I agree with your numbers now but I'm assuming that the waveform is zero for the rest of the time (65%). Maybe the answer you were told is incorrect?

Comment: yes you are right, it is zero for the rest.

Comment: Hey hold on a minute, you are applying the formula inappropriately. You have to apply it as if the sinewave between 54 degrees and 180 was repeated from 180 onwards. You are assuming a full sinewave from zero to 360 degrees and this breaks the rule of the formula.

Comment: sine wave conducts from 54 to 180 and repeated after 360 hence the duty cycle was 126/360.

Comment: What you are assuming is like saying that the RMS value of part of a sinewave is exactly the same as any other part of that sinewave and that is incorrect.

Comment: sine wave here is periodic with period 360 degree.

Comment: Think about this a bit. What if the sine window was from 89 to 91 degrees - the sine value is pretty much 1 in this area but if you focussed on 179 to 181 degrees the value is pretty much zero. You are misapplying the formula. The formula assumes that for time period d1, the waveform in d1 repeats for ever hence it's RMS value is totally represented by the waveform in d1. You are missapplying the formula because the partial sinewave has to repeat from 180 degrees onwards and you are not assuming this. You cannot solve your problem with this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52203/discussion-between-ansh-kumar-and-andy-aka).